Is there a version of the rank nullity theorem for finite groups?
I have a linear map from the generalized Pauli group (or better to say, the representation of it) as
$\Xi_M: M^\dagger P M$,
with $P$ being a Pauli element.
Can I say anything about connection of the kernel and the image of this map (can I apply a version of the rank-nullity theorem here)?

you have any info on $M$?

First isomorphism theorem.

M is a sum of unitary matrices
